# SQL sort order using 'ORDER BY CASE...'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I'm trying to create a sorting function in SQL but I cannot make this thing work. I have really tried to find some similar problem on Stackoverflow but non that seems to solve my problem. I really not an expert on this things so hope that my explanation is understandable.

So case is as follows: I will list out products an on the website I have links for the user to click that decides what will be sorted, ProductName, ProductID and so on. Chosen sort type is collected from a `request.querystring` and I use `CreateParameter` to avoid the risk of SQL injections.

Here is the (simplified) SQL:

```
"SELECT * FROM Product" & _
"ORDER BY CASE ? " & _
    "WHEN 'ID' THEN ProductID " & _
    "WHEN 'IDART' THEN ArticleNumber " & _
    "ELSE ProductName " & _
"END DESC"    

objConnProdList.CommandType = 1
SET objParam = objConnProdList.CreateParameter("@strOrder", adVarchar, adParamInput, 10,  "%" & request.querystring("OrderBy") & "%")
```

Using `ELSE` I will get the error message:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'DiningChair' to data type int.

Comment: I worked out this solution, It might not be perfect but it works. I thought implementing `ASC`, `DESC` would be the easy part I could not find a straight solution to solve this.  
  
`DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(10)  
SET @OrderBy = '"&request.querystring("OrderBy")& "_"&request.querystring("Dir")&"'  
  
SELECT * FROM Product  
ORDER BY  
CASE @OrderBy WHEN 'ID_ASC' then ProductID end ASC,  
CASE @OrderBy WHEN 'ID_DESC' then ProductID end DESC,  
CASE @OrderBy WHEN 'VARENR_ASC' then ArticleNumber end ASC,  
CASE @OrderBy WHEN 'VARENR_DESC' then ArticleNumber end DESC,  
END  `

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't mix different data types in a single case. The syntax would be ok if you convert the values to nvarchars, but that doesn't sort them properly.

If you're using dynamic SQL like in the example, just add the lines to order by you actually need. If you have a stored procedure or something like that, it works with separate order by clauses like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Product
ORDER BY 
  CASE @xxx WHEN 'ID' then ProductID end,
  case @xxx WHEN 'IDART' THEN ArticleNumber end,
  ProductName DESC
```

Comment: I'm upvoting, but it is possible that the OP wants `DESC` for each of the sorts.  Hard to tell unambiguously from the question, though.

Comment: I tried your solution but i can't figure out how to use/declare the `@xxx`.
Implementing your code gave me the error:
"Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, I will implement `DESC, ASC` later on but not vital for now.

Answer (score 0):

i think you make it overly complicated.

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Product";

switch (strOrder)
case when "ID": 
  sql = sql & " ORDER BY ProductID"
  break;
case when "IDART": 
  sql = sql & " ORDER BY ArticleID"
  break;
end;
```

and run it. there is no place for injection as there is no variable you inject.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation on JamesZ's answer:

```
with const as (
      select ? as xxx
     )
SELECT *
FROM const cross join Product
ORDER BY (CASE xxx WHEN 'ID' then ProductID end),
         (case xxx WHEN 'IDART' THEN ArticleNumber end),
         ProductName DESC
```

Comment: This looked like a very neat solution, I will try this one out.